# UITableView left-side multiple selection selected cell color

Tags: ios, uitableview, multipleselection, editmode

As a UITableView is `allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true`,

the default selection style is a light-blue look on a selected cell:

[image]

I set the cell `contentView.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()` when the cell got `highlighted`/ `selected`,

consequently make the circle-checkmark area remain light-blue but not the whole cell:

[image]

**TL;DR**

I need the whole cell to be white as it's multiple-selected,
 which means I cannot set the cell's `selectionStyle = .None`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: fake it by adding labels in a separate view and set that view's background color as white .And keep the selection color default for

Comment: You can set your custom view as a selectedBackgroundView of a cell.
In custom cell class, simply you can write this code
self.selectedBackgroundView = UIView(frame: rect)
        self.selectedBackgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()   Hope this may solve your issue.

Comment: @iOS_Binod works like a champ!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()` ?

Comment: Not working. Cell color would be changed when selected.